# Why this code works fine only on local server?

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn how to set cookies, and the following code works fine on local server but for some reason it doesn't on live server. Here is the code

```
<?php
  $test = 'false';
  if (isset($_COOKIE['test'])) $test = $_COOKIE['test'];
  echo "<p><b>The value of the cookie 'test' is: $test</b></p>";
  setcookie('test', 'I love cookies');
?>
```

I have done some searches and there is someone who had same problem, but he answered him self claiming that he figured out what is wrong. here is his answer :

It's done already. Problem was with setting cookies as headers had already been sent in that file, cookies were not saving. Now done.:)

So, What did he mean by that?

Comment: so in a remote computer you cannot set the cookie?

Comment: yes, when i try to use the same code with online server it doesn't generate cookies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you test both localhost and live server with same browser (with cookies enabled)?

EDIT:

Following your edit, you should set cookies BEFORE you sent ANY output like echo, print_r etc... as setCookie command sends to a browser with headers, and all headers should be sent before output. Your code should look like that:

```
  $test = 'false';
  if (isset($_COOKIE['test'])) $test = $_COOKIE['test'];
  setcookie('test', 'I love cookies');
  echo "<p><b>The value of the cookie 'test' is: $test</b></p>";
```

If you really need to perform some action with output BEFORE you set cookie, you can use output bufer:

```
  $test = 'false';
  if (isset($_COOKIE['test'])) $test = $_COOKIE['test'];

  ob_start();
  echo "<p><b>The value of the cookie 'test' is: $test</b></p>";
  $buffer = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  setcookie('test', 'I love cookies');
  echo $buffer;
```

Comment: What you see? Always 'false'?

Comment: yes always 'false'.Does it has any thing to do with server time?

Comment: Not really. It should set cookie until browser will not be closed. What server / php version do you use? What browser? Is that behavior similar for all browsers?

Comment: try to set cookie with expiration time (one hour): setcookie('test', 'I love cookies', time()+3600);

Comment: it is php and on any browser it is the same result.please i have edited the question. would you please check it ?

Comment: No thing change when setting expiry

Comment: You are welcome. Btw, that code could not work on your localhost either, it was working only because you did setcookie('test', 'I love cookies'); before adding top lines.